# improving wordpress rest api speed

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a simple wordpress plugin that defines an endpoint.

I need to load only core wordpress functionality so i can improve response times. Below is the content of my wordpress plugin

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Vunjabei plugin
 * Plugin URI: http://hawavunjabei.com/vunjabei
 * Description: A plugin for customizing Hawa vunjabei wordpress stack
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: oxo africa
 * Author URI: http://www.oxoafrica.co.tz
 */

// Tell WordPress to only load the basics
define('SHORTINIT',1);

// get path of wp-load.php and load it
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'v1', '/getTime', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'woocommerceSimpleRoute',
  ) );
} );


function woocommerceSimpleRoute( $data ) {
    wp_send_json( array( 'time' => time() ) );

}
```

**Calling the endpoint /v1/getTime via the plugin returns a response in 1.5seconds, that's pretty bad for such a simple request.**

> If i put the script in a plain php file , the result is remarkable , the response gets returned in only **300 milliseconds**

How can i fine tune the plugin version to improve the response speed ?

Comment: Did you get an answer to your problem ? I experience the same situation on a production server.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you don't use any additional WP plugins, just WordPress out of the box. So they cann't slow your site.

Do you run your website locally (on Windows machine or what over) or using some hosting (on Linux or what over)? Sometimes local env is slow/unoptimized.

You should also understand that in the process of WP initializing there are many calculations that a typical PHP file does not do.

Without specifics, I can only advise enable caching via some existing WP plugins.